# Menu tabs are disoriented upon collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, frontend

My code for this is :

```
    <!-- page content -->   
    <div class="right_col" role="main">
        <c:if test="${not empty menuStructure.menus}">
          <div class="row">
            <c:forEach var="menu" items="${menuStructure.menus}" 
             varStatus="menuCounter">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
              <div class="x_panel tile">
                <div class="x_title">
                <span style="font-size: 25px; color: #73879C !important; font- 
                   weight:bold; font-size:1.0vw; margin-top:15px; font-weight: 
                   400;">${menu.label}</span>
                   <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                     <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"> 
                         </i></a>
                     </li>                   </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
           </div>
          <div class="x_content" align="center" >
              <a href="${menu.link}"><img 
                   src="${contextPath}/resources/images/${menu.thumbnail}"  
                   alt=""></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </c:forEach>
   </div>
  </c:if> 
 </div>   
 <!-- /page content -->
```

I know that the issue is that all menu tabs are contained in bootstrap class `class="row"` that's why when last tab of first row is collapsed that space is reclaimed by the tabs below it, but I'm unable to find a solution for this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your structure a bit, like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

means 12 columns should be in single row, so you wont get above issue

Comment: I get your solution but problem is that i never know exact number of menus being loaded, that comes from server. So i have to loop it through and then generate html.

Comment: then you need to provide some `min-height` to your columns like ex: 300px, so when you collapsed a div your parent column height will not affect... hope that make sens

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child in css as 
.right_col .col-md-3:nth-child(n+4){
 clear: both;
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
function alignGrid(){
   $(".sp-custom").remove();
   var width=$(".row").width()-30;
   var temp=0;
   $(".row .grid-custom").each(function(index, item) {
     temp=temp+$(item).width();
     if((width-temp)<$(item).width()){    
        $(item).after('<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 sp-custom"></div>');
        temp=0;
     }
  });
}
alignGrid();

$( window ).resize(function() {  
  alignGrid();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:grey;height:100px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:green;height:100px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:lightgrey;height:40px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;height:100px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;height:80px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:blue;height:10px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:cyan;height:100px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:lightblue;height:70px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:black;height:70px;">
      </div>
      <div class="grid-custom col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:brown;height:100px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can try the above javascript code.
This code will insert div as a separator after the last div in a row.

Comment: This code will create row after each tab, i want row after every 4th tab.

Comment: It will create row after 4th tab or according to screen size. For example, if the row has three column then it will insert after 3rd tab.

Comment: You will require jquery to run this code. you can use this script tag for jquery <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I'm using jQuery but this code does not add another row after 3rd column.

Comment: I have updated the above code. The problem may be due to multiple div in a grid so I have provided a custom class specific to a grid. Try this code. This is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/chundawatchatar/xz9zc1v3/